# Creating many small databases to be accessed by a webapp

Tags: java, database

I have this requirement for my business. We have a swing desktop application that works with a mysql database. At the end of each day the swing app exports the data that has changed and uploads it to a server. The set up is, a user working in an office, will have many companies that he is working with. If he changes any data for that company, then I export that company's data alone from the database. The data is exported in the form of java objects, serialised and stored into a file which gets uploaded.

The next day, if there are any changes made to that company again then I will replace the file in the server with the latest uploaded file.

Now on my server, I would like to work with this file. I would like to convert each of these files into mini databases that a webapp can read. It will not write to it. Everytime the user uploads, the database will be deleted and recreated.

So ultimately each of these files are a small subset of the data that a user has in his desktop application.

Now this issues are:

1. The objects that I have exported are "Apache Torque" objects. Torque is an ORM tool, basically the object represents the table. I need to convert this object into a database. Sqlite, HSQLDB, Derby...? The database should be small. If the object file is about 5KB, then the database that represents that file shouldnt be 3MB. Derby did that actually.
2. The java object classes could change. Since the underlying database could change. Hence I will need to deserialise these objects and create a database from it as soon as it is uploaded. Otherwise, I will not be able to deserialise these objects later on. Small changes to the database is fine for the web application. But if I dont deserialise it immediately, then I am stuck.
3. The conversion from the java object to the database should be fast. Since the user actually waits when his data is getting uploaded I would like to add a maximum of 5-10s additional for the conversion.
4. Is it ok to have thousands of these mini databases lying around? Is this design okay? Is there an alternate solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't try to put each dataset into its own database. I would put all of them in one big database, along with a column in the key tables indicating the dataset that each row applies to (this sounds like it should just be a company identifier). This is a more normalised design than having many small databases.

You will then need to write the webapp so it makes queries for particular datasets, rather than connecting to a particular database.

if you adopt that approach, you can deserialize and store the datasets as soon as they arrive. The storage is simply inserting rows into an existing database, so it should be very fast.

In addition, i expect that one big database will be much easier to manage, maintain, report on, etc, than many small databases.

If you tell us more about the details of your schema, we could discuss how the database could be organised, if that would be useful.

Comment: +1 for using the same database. Lot easier to maintain from a DBA perspective and easier to code against (only one JDBC connection instead of n where n is the # of proposed databases, for instance).

Comment: +1 for storing the data in a single database instead of many very small databases. It gains you simplicity and speed, and as a non-requirement bonus you can easily query your single database to generate statistics that might help you fine-tune your solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Since there is a shortage of time I will not be able to unfortunately combine all the databases into one big schema. Each table will need to be modified to include a company identifier like you have suggested above. How about creating multiple schemas in a single mysql instance? I will create one schema for each user, not one schema for each company as described above. This will drastically reduce the number of schemas as well. If there is any change in the database schema, then as soon as the data gets uploaded by the user, I will apply the schema changes first.

Comment: Continuing from above.. I will apply the schema changes first, delete the records pertaining to that company and then insert the data from the deserialised object when the data gets uploaded. Do you guys think this will fly? I switched to mysql instead of other file based databases, because if I run any of these databases in the embedded mode, then if there is a load balancer introduced for my server, then there will be issues. There will more jvms trying to connect to the same database.

Comment: To be honest, that doesn't sound like a great idea. Bear in mind that you don't necessarily need to add a company identifier to every table, just to the "persistent roots" - say you have a table of contracts, and a table of support calls, each referencing a contract, then you would need to put a company identifier on the contracts, but not the support calls, because those would already be indirectly associated with a company, through the contract. I doubt that the work involved in adjusting your database is more than the work involved in getting a multi-schema setup to work properly.

Comment: Thanks Tom.. that was just an idea.. :) Did some more thinking, and felt that might not work. Getting multiple schemas might not work. We came up with another idea. How about converting that serialised object file, into a view file. Meaning, I would obtain the data from the serialised objects and create a file that is more aligned to the web application's view. Using Xstream, I could create a JSON file that can be directly consumed by the web application. So no querying, and database management required. Its only a flat file that can be read by multiple processes.

Comment: Continuing.. The web application, is low traffic, and is pretty simple- meaning not too many screens. I could create very small json files that are screen oriented. If some querying is required, it will be very minimal, the json data can be filtered on the browser via java script. This seemed a simpler approach.. If there are any view changes, then we will just re run the batch that created the view file from the serialised object file and obtain the additional data required.

Comment: We decided ultimately to go with your suggestion :) The tight coupling with view files wouldnt work later. No harm trying different approaches first though right?... Thanks a ton..

Comment: Definitely no harm thinking about different approaches. If nothing else, it helps you understand why you are doing what you are doing.